# Does StackExchange.Redis Use Local in Memory Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, stackexchange.redis

StackExchange.Redis Seems to be a popular Redis C# Client. I am unclear on whether StackExchange.Redis uses Multi-Level Caching?

That is If I call the following code numerous times from Asp.net WebSite; Does the Redis Client skip traveling over the wire and instead use the local (Asp.net Built-in Memory Cache)? Or is it the case That We will query an actual redis node each and every-time?

```
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
string value = db.StringGet("mykey");
```

Comment: The value can be changed, so the method must get the value from the server every time to return the latest value.

Comment: StackExchange.Redis does not use Local in Memory Cache. You can add this yourself in your application code.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat dated question, but maybe still useful: if you need a .net multi-level cache with a local in memory layer and an optional distributed one (eg: Redis) all managed transparently for you may I suggest you to take a look at [FusionCache](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache) ?

I just released it and it would be great if you find it helpful in some ways.

You may also find some of the other features interesting, like the [cache stampede prevention](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/blob/main/docs/CacheStampede.md) to avoid multiple concurrent factory calls at the same time for the same cache key, a [fail-safe](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/FailSafe.md) mechanism, [advanced timeouts](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/Timeouts.md) with background factory completion and support for an optional, distributed [2nd level](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/blob/main/docs/CacheLevels.md).

If you will give it a chance please let me know what you think.

/shameless-plug